# Vector matrix multiplication behavior with GLM?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, glm-math

I am by no means a mathematician, and I'm trying to understand what's happening with GLM's multiplication between vectors and matrices. From what I understand, GLM's matrices are sized as columns x rows, and in normal matrix multiplication in GLM, the left hand side of the expression must have the same amount of columns as the right hand side has rows. So here's where my question comes in.

The thing that confuses me is that I can multiply a 2x3 matrix by a three dimensional vector

```
| 1, 4 |
| 2, 5 | x [ 1, 2, 3 ]
| 3, 6 |
```

giving me an answer of `[ 9, 12, 15 ]`. But I can also multiply a 3x2 matrix by the same 3D vector

```
| 1, 3, 5 |
| 2, 4, 6 | x [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

and I now get a 2-dimensional vector of `[ 22, 28 ]`. Why is this possible? What is happening here?

What confuses me further is that I can switch the order and put the vector on the left hand side and the matrix on the right, and I still get a valid result. Again, why is this possible?  What is happening? And is this GLM-specific behavior, or is it standard matrix behavior?

I apologize if this is easy math, however after many hours of searching the internet and testing by myself with GLM, I still do not understand the concept. I appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is a code example

```cpp
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL

#include <iostream>
#include <glm/mat2x3.hpp>
#include <glm/mat3x2.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>

int main() {
    glm::mat2x3 a = {
        1, 2, 3, 
        4, 5, 6
    };

    glm::mat3x2 b = {
        1, 2,
        3, 4,
        5, 6
    };

    glm::vec3 c = {
       1, 2, 3
    };

    // These all compile correctly? And each gives different results.
    std::cout << glm::to_string(a * c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << glm::to_string(c * a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << glm::to_string(b * c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << glm::to_string(c * b) << std::endl;
}
```

The console output is the following

```
vec3(9.000000, 12.000000, 15.000000)
vec2(14.000000, 32.000000)
vec2(22.000000, 28.000000)
vec3(5.000000, 11.000000, 17.000000)
```

Comment: Matrices are defined as row X column. Your visualization is wrong (same for vectors)

Comment: @RoQuOTriX row length X column length, or amount of rows X amount of columns? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think the correct is amount of rows X amount of columns. I don't understand what you mean with length of a row? The number of elements in this row? This would be the amount of columns and vice versa... If you have 3x1 matrix (a vector) it has 3 rows and 1 column, not 1 row and 3 columns

Comment: You need a linear algebra course.  The number of columns in matrix A must equal the number of rows in matrix B when you multiply two matricies.  Your first example should show a 1x3 vector pre-multiplying a 3x2 matrix to give a 1x2 matrix.  Your second example shows a 2x3 matrix post-multiplying what should be a 3x1 column vector to give a 2x1 matrix.  Your visuals are both incorrect.  Matrix multiplication is not commutative: A x B may not equal B x A.

Comment: @duffymo sorry, I mentioned incorrectly that GLM stores matrices as rows x columns, but it’s actually columns x rows (column-major?). I edited the question to correct that. I realize that even this correction doesn’t seem to make these examples work, but I’m asking because each of them actually did compile and produced valid responses in GLM, which I listed. So I am asking specifically about the GLM library, which as far as I understand has several unconventional behaviors.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX thanks, that helps a bit. Is this for GLM or just in general?

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:glm], did you mean [tag:glm-math]?

Comment: The internal storage is immaterial.  My comment is true regardless of how they choose to store the values in memory.  GLM and all other data analysis algorithms are all based on linear algebra and must behave accordingly.

Comment: @genpfault Shoot, you are right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @duffymo as genpfault pointed out, I tagged the question incorrectly. By GLM, I was meaning the OpenGL Math library, not generalized linear model. Was this the point of confusion? I apologize for the mixup.

Comment: Not for me.  What I said is true for all linear algebra implementations.

Comment: @duffymo Okay, I added a code example to illustrate what I mean. Whether it's supposed to or not, it works with GLM. Hopefully showing this directly can explain better than I can with words. I should have had this from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going on! The problem ended up having nothing to do with matrices at all, but rather a quirk of GLM. In the code example, `a * c` and `c * b` are able to compile because `c` is being implicitly casted to a two-dimensional vector without any warning. Simple as that, but very confusing!